# Covariant divergence in xAct

Tags: xact

I'm using xAct for calculation of expansion scalar for Kerr in Boyer-Linquist coordinates. Expansion scalar is given as a covariant divergence:
[image]

with  [image]

where \Delta and \Sigma are defined as [image]

In the following code I'm setting a metric in B-L coordinates, defining null vector *k* and then calculating expansion as a covariant divergence of *k*:

```
<< xAct`xCoba`
DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f}]
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
DefChart[BL, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}, 
FormatBasis -> {"Partials", "Differentials"}]
$Assumptions = 
t[] \[Element] Reals && r[] > 0 && 0 < \[Theta][] < Pi && 
0 < \[Phi][] < 2 Pi;
DefConstantSymbol[Mass, PrintAs -> "M"]
DefConstantSymbol[Rotation, PrintAs -> "a"]

metricBL = {{-(1 - 2 Mass r[]/(r[]^2 + Rotation^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)),
0, 0, -2 Mass r[] Rotation Sin[\[Theta][]]^2/(r[]^2 + 
   Rotation^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)}, {0, (r[]^2 + 
  Rotation^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)/(r[]^2 - 2 Mass r[] + Rotation^2),
0, 0}, {0, 0, r[]^2 + Rotation^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2, 
0}, {-2 Mass r[] Rotation Sin[\[Theta][]]^2/(r[]^2 + 
   Rotation^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2), 0, 
0, ((r[]^2 + Rotation^2)^2 - (r[]^2 - 2 Mass r[] + 
     Rotation^2) Rotation^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2) \
Sin[\[Theta][]]^2/(r[]^2 + Rotation^2 Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)}}

metricBL = CTensor[metricBL, {-BL, -BL}, 0]
SetCMetric[metricBL, BL, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]
MetricCompute[metricBL, BL, All, Verbose -> True]
cd = CovDOfMetric[metricBL]

k := CTensor[{(r[]^2 + 
  Rotation^2)/(2*(r[]^2 + 
    Rotation^2*Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)), (r[]^2 - 2 Mass*r[] + 
  Rotation^2)/(2*(r[]^2 + Rotation^2*Cos[\[Theta][]]^2)), 0, 
Rotation/(2*(r[]^2 + Rotation^2*Cos[\[Theta][]]^2))}, {BL}, 0]

Expansion = cd[-a]@(k[a]) // Simplify
Simplify[cd[-a]@(k[a]), \[CapitalSigma] == 
r[]^2 + Rotation^2*Cos[\[Theta][]]^2]
```

The problem is that expansion calculated with xAct is different from that is given in aricles.

Article: [image]

xAct: [image]

Am I doing something wrong with my code? Am I missing out on something? Please help.

Comment: Your code for k is different from the formula you quote above. If you copy the quoted formula then you get the expected answer.

Comment: My bad, I accidentally put the wrong formula for k, thanks a lot for pointing this out, Jose!